# Does everything done through GUI (in Windows) have a command line equivalent?

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-prompt

Does everything you do in the GUI in windows (i.e. through pointing, clicking and typing) have a command line equivalent, or are there some things (or maybe a lot of things) the command prompt can’t do?

FYI I'm very new to using the command line and just curious

Comment: I don't see a specific programming question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does not guarantee that, but it does gradually allow every changes on UI to have a related PowerShell cmdlet.

Thus, you'd better check out PowerShell, which is more related to server management, than programming.